# What is int (*) [ someValue] in c++?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I am just learning c++ in my college.
I tried to compile the code from GitHub to solve Rubiks cube. And i got a error on the following line of code:

```
  Table = int (*)[Cube::Move::NumberOfClockwiseQuarterTurnMoves] // the cast
```

The error message is:

```
MoveTable.cpp   [Error] expected primary-expression before 'int'
```

I used dev-c++ IDE to compile and I am not familiar with `int(*)[]`.
Please someone tell me what is it and how can i correct that?

I did some research and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253509/type-of-int-int-int). Is it same as my question? It seems a bit different. And I am not asking for `int *(int*)=constant` like asked [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636819/meaning-of-int-int-5-or-any-integer-value)

Edit: I forgot to include full statement before i.e.

```
Table = (int (*)[Cube::NumberOfClockwiseQuarterTurnMoves] )// the cast
    (new int[TableSize*Cube::NumberOfClockwiseQuarterTurnMoves]);
```

And I got these errors.

```
    [Error] expected primary-expression before 'int'
    [Error] expected ')' before 'int'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of int (\*) (int \*) = 5 (or any integer value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636819/meaning-of-int-int-5-or-any-integer-value)

Comment: this is different from the above.

Comment: Please give a [mcve] which exactly reproduces the issue you are asking about. The code you have shown here has several compiler errors unrelated to your question. This makes your question unanswerable because the code is not even valid.

Comment: That line doesn't make sense. It doesn't even have `;`.

Comment: The [GitHub original](https://github.com/petcomputacaoufrgs/roborubik/blob/master/ANTIGO/Algor%C3%ADtmo%20de%20Solução%20(ANTIGO)/Kociemba%20Rubik%20Solver%20(linux)/KociembaRubikSolver/MOVETABL.CPP) looks different and there is a second line in the statement. Is this just a typo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short**

The answer to your question title is:  `int(*)[someConstant]` corresponds to a type that is *a pointer to a table of `someConstant` items each  of type `int`.*

**All the details**

In C++ a valid statement ends with a semi-column, so there is a part missing in the statement.  In addition the comment shows that this is only the cast part.

In the original [project file](https://github.com/petcomputacaoufrgs/roborubik/blob/master/ANTIGO/Algor%C3%ADtmo%20de%20Solu%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20(ANTIGO)/Kociemba%20Rubik%20Solver%20(linux)/KociembaRubikSolver/MOVETABL.CPP) on GitHub, the full statement is:

```
Table = (int (*)[Cube::Move::NumberOfClockwiseQuarterTurnMoves]) // the cast
        (new int[TableSize*Cube::Move::NumberOfClockwiseQuarterTurnMoves]); // the allocation
```

This cast means that the pointer that will be returned by the expression is to be handled as a pointer to a table of `NumberOfClockwiseQuarterTurnMoves` integers, even if in reality a pointer to a larger table is returned by the `new` expression.

Removing the bracket before the before the `int` as in you did makes this an invalid statement, because  `int (*)[Cube::Move::NumberOfClockwiseQuarterTurnMoves]` is a type, and it's not allowed to use a type like this in an expression without the correct casting operator.  The compiler therefore tells you that it expects a real expression (that will provide a real value).

***P.S.***: this has indeed nothing to do with questions related to `int (*)()` which refer to a function pointer to function returning an int

Comment: I compiled the original codes and I got the error as I edited in the question.

Comment: @UmeshShrestha ok, can you please clarify the version of your compiler and the compile options ?